# Get attendees of a facebook event with Graph API without login javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to get a list of people attending an open Facebook event. I can achieve this if the user logins first as it seems to require an access token.

```
FB.api(
"/{event-id}/attending",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
} );
```

However I don't want the user to have to login first, is there any way I can get the list of people attending without having to log in first? I mean it's an open event so surely there is a way?

Thank you kindly

Comment: Check the documentation, it tells you hat kinds of access token you can use.

Comment: It says I can use any I want, but I need to get an access token first, right? How do I get one without having them to log in?

Comment: Well you could use your app access token – if you are willing to move this to the server side. (The app access token should __never__ be exposed in client-side code.) If that’s not an option – then you _will_ have to have users login first, so you can use their user access token.

Comment: Yes that is an option, but (possibly a silly question, but bare with me) how do you actually _use_ the app's access token in this way? 
Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Depends on how you will be making the request server-side, using any SDK, or on your own … basically it has just to be passed as a parameter named `access_token` in the Graph API call.